# How to inherit class instance's state from constructor argument?

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

I would like to share a state of an instance to multiple children, so they share the parent's state together.

This is a working example:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myValues = []

    def my_add(self, x):
        self.myValues.append(x)


class Worker(Stack):

    def __init__(self, my_stack):
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mystack = Stack()
    worker1 = Worker(mystack)
    worker2 = Worker(mystack)

    worker1.my_add(4)
    worker2.my_add(5)

    print(len(mystack.myValues))
    print(len(worker1.myValues))
    print(len(worker2.myValues))
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```

I need the output to be "2 2 2", so share the instance and state of `mystack` to `worker1` and `worker2` **without** `self.mystack=mystack` in the constructor of class `Worker`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Worker` class ignores the `Stack` instance passed to it. This isn't a job for inheritance. Instances of `Worker` *use* an instance of `Stack`; they should not themselves *be* instances of `Stack`.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myValues = []

    def my_add(self, x):
        self.myValues.append(x)


class Worker:    
    def __init__(self, my_stack):
        self.stack = my_stack

    def my_add(self, x):
        self.stack.my_add(x)

    @property
    def myValues(self):
        return self.stack.myValues
```